# Getting null value while passing a bitmap to imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am trying to pass a `bitmap` value to an `imageView` to show it on camera screen as thumbnail just after a `video` is recorded from `camera`.(I am trying to build a custom camera)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createVideoFolder();

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);

    mRecordImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);
    mRecordImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mIsRecording) {
                mChronometer.stop();
                mChronometer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mIsRecording = false;
                mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.start_recording);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();


                Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoFileName , MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmapView);      // in this line i am getting null value
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

Comment: Please add logs

Comment: And layout file, are you sure your imageview id matches?

Comment: are you sure there is imageview named **bitmapView** in your xml **activity_main** layout ?

Comment: yes @Nishant Pardamwar

Comment: here the xml code
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bitmapView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: this is not going to solve problem, but not findviewById everytime you click on button move out just beneath setContentView(...)

Comment: i m new to android, so could you give an example how to use setContentView in my code @Xenione